# Element not pushing away from immediate parent Div

Tags: html, css

Why does a `<h#>` elements margin by default (user agent stylesheet) not push a parent `div` away?

The `<h2>` element pushes away from the browser window instead.

**Edit:** opening the below as a html document in chrome. The div is immediately next to the `<h2>` element but is pushed away from the browser window due to the margin on the `<h2>`

**Edit 2:** Added a `margin-top:50px` to the `<h2>`. Why is the `div` not affected by this margin?

[image]

```
<html>
   <div id="does-not-push-away">
        <h2>Heading<h2>
    <div>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by push the `div` away?  Maybe a fiddle example would be helpful to understand the question.

Comment: Sorry cant use fiddle at work, I will edit the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about *margin collapse*, I believe. One of three basic types. Here's a relevant paragraph from [MDN's explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing):

> If there is no border, padding, inline
>   content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the
>   margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline
>   content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the
>   margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child,
>   then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the
>   parent.

Your parent block is your `<div id="does-not-push-away">`, and its first child is your `<h2>`. Add 1px of padding (or a transparent border, or anything) to the `<div>` and you should see all of `<h2>`'s margin "push it away".

Here's a pen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/MisterGrumpyPants/pen/fLmqF (notice how the same margin collapse occurs with the margin-bottom I applied to the `<h2>` elements --)

Answer (score 1):

`<h2>` certainly has default margin value. You can see a difference by adding css :

```
.does-not-push-away{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 5px;
}
.does-not-push-away h2{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Okay brother, here is the facts:

1. `<h2>` as default has a margin. You can see to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/MgLcf/)
2. In the image, you give `<h2>` a `margin-top`. The `<div>` certainly not affected for the margin because you give the `margin-top` property to `<h2>`

If you want the `<div>` get a margin too, you should give `margin-top` too. You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/MgLcf/1/). Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Why does the margin not push away the `div`? @Aldi Unanto

Comment: Sorry I don't get 'push away' as you told. But during your `<h2>` inside `<div>` , the `<div>` will be a still frame for `<h2>` itself. Don't worry about that. Or could you give a fiddle sample? To make me more understand of your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` on the `div` rather than border or padding like stated in the other answers.